# Is there a way to quickly get an overview of the existing routes (like 'rails routes') for AngularJS with UIRouter?

Tags: angularjs

Having worked with Rails for some time, I was using 'rails routes' quite often to get a quick overview of the existing routes in a project.

Now I am working on an Angularjs project (~1.48). Is there some way to get an overview of the routes defined for a project?

Comment: You can search for where ever your ngRoute is implemented on your app.  This is usually done within the configuration.  Without really knowing the layout of your application is, it would be hard to really answer this.  But where ever your ngRoute is injected there will be Routes.  Kind of a long road version of 'rails routes'

Comment: You also have to take into consideration of Directives and Components as they will have routes in the templateUrl as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `$state.get()`

Try to use this inside your controller:

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($state) {
  console.log(angular.toJson($state.get()));
});
```

Here is the doc for this:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ui.router.state.$state#get
 * @methodOf ui.router.state.$state
 *
 * @description
 * Returns the state configuration object for any state by passing the name
 * as a string. Without any arguments it'll return a array of all configured
 * state objects.
 *
 * @param {string|object} stateOrName The name of the state for which you'd like 
 * to get the original state configuration object for.
 * @returns {object} State configuration object or array of all objects.
 */
```

Comment: Great! Good luck.